# How do I parse custom url into a calendar event?

Tags: android, parsing, url, calendar, jsoup

what I am trying to do is, with this custom url of mine

```
(mlevents://add/event?day=8&month=10&year=2014&timestring=12:00 PM - 12:30 PM &hourS=12&minuteS=00&hourE=12&minuteE=30&title=Filene 101: Think. Do. Change. | Webinar&timezone=CST)
```

be able to parse and save as a calendar event that will store to Google Calendar, I have had no luck with it and I have mlevents set up as a custom scheme in my manifest.xml but still no luck. How would I go about setting this up so it works correctly?

Comment: you want to get : the day , the month , the year , the timestring , and the time etc.. !

Comment: @ZiedRebhi true but I guess what I am unsure of is how to grab that data effectively, I know how to pass it to calendars after I have the data, but when a mlevents url pops up in my webview I do not know how to grab the info and store it.

Comment: @ZiedRebhi I have been reading up on JSOUP for the past hour or so, Wondering if that would be the most effective way and if so I need help learning how to use it in this way, or a link to a nice tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the String.split method which takes a regex pattern, depending on what you want you need to change the pattern - but to split the string on "&" then for each string in array use "=" you do do this: This is a full code : tru

```
public class Event {
String[] myStringArr;

int day;
int month;
int year;
String timeString;
int hourS;
int minuteS;
int hourE;
int minuteE;
String title;
String timezone;

public int getDay() {
    return Integer.parseInt(myStringArr[0].split("=")[1]);
}

public int getMonth() {
    return Integer.parseInt(myStringArr[1].split("=")[1]);
}

public int getYear() {
    return Integer.parseInt(myStringArr[2].split("=")[1]);
}

public String getTimeString() {
    return myStringArr[3].split("=")[1];
}

public int getHourS() {
    return Integer.parseInt(myStringArr[4].split("=")[1]);
}

public int getMinuteS() {
    return Integer.parseInt(myStringArr[5].split("=")[1]);
}

public int getHourE() {
    return Integer.parseInt(myStringArr[6].split("=")[1]);
}

public int getMinuteE() {
    return Integer.parseInt(myStringArr[7].split("=")[1]);
}

public String getTitle() {
    return myStringArr[8].split("=")[1];
}

public String getTimezone() {
    return myStringArr[9].split("=")[1];
}

public Event(String[] myStringArr) {
    super();
    this.myStringArr = myStringArr;
}
```

}

in your activity :

```
    String customUrl = "(mlevents://add/event?day=8&month=10&year=2014&timestring=12:00 PM - 12:30 PM &hourS=12&minuteS=00&hourE=12&minuteE=30&title=Filene 101: Think. Do. Change. | Webinar&timezone=CST)";
    final String[] myStringArr = customUrl.split("&");
    Event event = new Event(myStringArr);   

    System.out.println(event.getDay()); // -> return 8 : the day 
    System.out.println(event.getTitle()); // return Filene 101: Think. Do. Change. | Webinar 

   // etc.. your variable event contains all data from your url , 
  // to get an info just call : event.getWhatYouWant();
```

Comment: yes this would work if I had one default url, but the event will change depending on what events they decide to click on, is there any "universal" way to achieve this the parameters will always be the say in that order, but the variables will change.

Comment: can u give me onther example of url !

Comment: of course! thanks so much for baring with me

 [link]mlevents://add/event?day=24&month=10&year=2014&timestring=7:30 AM - 8:30 AM &hourS=07&minuteS=30&hourE=08&minuteE=30&title=Event Title&timezone=PST[/link]

as you can tell it has the same layout, just different variables.

Comment: oh my you are more than great! i have been struggling with this for about a week and someone told me to turn here, if you need any further info please let me know.

Comment: ok :) , i will write a method that you give it a string (url) and return an object Event whitch contains all of data in url (day , month, year, tilte etc..)

Comment: that sounds like exactly what I was going for :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63562/discussion-between-bumbob-and-zied-rebhi).